# Online tool for picking points on the 2D plane and exporting them to coordinates)

Tags: plot, visualization, data-visualization, data-generation

I am looking for a specific online tool. At first it displays empty 2D plot (with gridlines from -10 to 10 for example). You can also choose a color. When I select a color and then click on the plot a new point should be drawn on the plot. I can click multiple times so that multiple points are generated on the plot. Then I can change the color and generate more points on the same plot (but with different color). When I'm done I should be able to export the points to list of coordinates and color: [(0, 1, 'blue'), (1, 1, 'green'), (1, 2, 'green')].

Does anyone know such tool? It's purpose is to simply quickly generate 2D dataset with multiple classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to find a tool that would exactly meet all your requirements but I think there is a solution that my fulfill some of them.
You can use plotly (https://plot.ly/create/) to plot visualize the points using scatter plot creator.
As for random points you can generate them randomly as well as assign colors to them using some simple python function, like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random
def make_points(minv,maxv,total):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.uniform(low=minv, high=maxv, size=(total,2)), columns=list('XY'))
    arr=["blue", "green", "purple", "red"]
    arr *= total // len(arr)
    random.shuffle(arr)
    df['color'] = arr
    df.to_csv("points")
    return df

make_points(-10,10,100)
```

This for example will create a dataframe with 100 2d points that can get values from -10, 10, and each is randomly assigned one of 4 colors.

Import the csv in the plotly chart creator and you can then manually edit the values if you like.